# Javascript regex match XML closing tag when on one line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match the very last closing tag of an XML string, both when they are on the same line or they are on separate lines.

case 1:

```
</any></any>
```

case 2:

```
  </any>
</any>
```

case 3:

```
  </any>

</any>
```

So in the above cases I have to match the very last `</any>` tag even when they are on same/separate line or if they have whitespace before/after.

All I could do is `/([^\s].+)$/g`, but that would only match the last one when they are on separate lines. If they are on the same lines I get both back.

How can I make it work?

Playground link:
https://regexr.com/4idl7

Comment: Maybe `/<\/any>(?![\s\S]*<\/any>)/` / `/<\/[^>]*>(?![\s\S]*<\/[^>]*>)/` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/ug3vw3/2

Comment: Thanks, it works! If you make it an answer I accept it as a solution.

Comment: Do not use regex to parsing XML! You'll get yourself headache and will end up with buggy semi working solution. Use other more appropriate tools designed to parse and process XML.

Comment: You are right @JánStibila but I don't need parsing the whole thing (including all the nested children), I just need to identify the opening and closing tag and the text inbetween.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/<\/[^>]*>(?![\s\S]*<\/[^>]*>)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ug3vw3/2).

Since the expected match is always single, there is no point using the `g` modifier.

**Details**

- `<\/[^>]*>` - `</`, any 0+ chars other than `>` and a `>`
- `(?![\s\S]*<\/[^>]*>)` - no any 0+ chars (`[\s\S]*`) followed with `</`, any 0+ chars other than `>` and a `>` immediately to the right of the current location are allowed.

Comment: Ultimately what I'm after is to capture the opening tag, the closing tag any anything inbetween.

Comment: @marchello Then *ultimately* use a DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not DOM related and I don't to parse any nested tags inbetween the opening and closing tag. Just open tag, closing tag and anything inbetween.

Comment: @marchello There are solutions for that, e.g. `/<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]*)?>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1>/g` (not the most efficient one though).